# android vertical ScrollView layout, make ImageView has fix percentage of screen height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-layout-weight

Hi I am new to android development.
I want to design an vertical ScrollView which contains a ImageView and TextView. ImageView occupies top 50% height of screen, and the bottom part is TextView with dynamic content, which may occupy less or more than 50% height of screen height. So ScrollView will be scrollable only if text content occupies 50% more of screen ( please see below for example)
[image: in this case text occupies 50% more screen so user has to scroll down to read more]

Is there any way to achieve this layout?

Comment: Try LinearLayout Weight Sum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/scroll_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/scroll_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This is the layout. In your activity, you should set the `ImageView`'s height as 50% of the screen height, like this:

```
ImageView scrollImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.scroll_image);
TextView scrollText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scroll_text);
int height = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;

LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) scrollImage.getLayoutParams();
params.height = height / 2;
scrollImage.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code

```
<ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:weightSum="100"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/scroll_image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:layout_weight="50" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/scroll_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="50" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
```